# Can not scrolling on mobile browser Until clicking menu dropdown button

Tags: android, css

This is my first time I'm asking on stackoverflow. My website got a problem that is hard to understand.The problem is that is I can not scroll down my website on mobile browsers **(Android + Chrome)**. But when I click on menu button I can scroll smoothly. When I check on desktop (Mobile screen) it does not encounter such problem so I can't debug to fix.

I need help guys. Other pages on website works normally. But homepage is different.

My website is : http://vanphongcanhochothue.com.

Comment: Please provide your code that's giving the issue so people can diagnose it.

Comment: Thank you !. But i don't even know which code made this problem. If i knew sure i can manually fix it. Sorry but no code even i can't use firebug on my mobile to fix - i really got upset about this.